# Any 3rd party packages used by Angular 4 in run-time (except RxJS)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, rxjs

Angular 4 uses some RxJS types in its public API as well as depends on RxJS internally.

Thinking further on this, it might be good to know if Angular uses other packages for parts of its run-time functionality, so we could use them as well. It might prevent us from introducing extra dependencies for the app by re-using them from Angular.

But looking into `node_modules`, every  Angular 4 app contains a massive amount of packages. Obviously, most of them doesn't get included in the run-time app bundle. At the same time, some of them (like lodash) could be very desirable to use in your Angular app as well.

So, is Angular based on any other packages except RxJS and which of them could be used  in our own code similar to RxJS?

Comment: The question is off-topic and cannot gain a quality answer. *some of them (like lodash) could be very desirable to use* - or they couldn't. It's up to you if Lodash will be used or not. And so will any other library. The question is pointless because it considers dependency a sort of a restraint, while it isn't. Dependency's footprint is. The relationship with RxJS is special because Angular *currently* relies on it (until native observables will become available) - and not on any other library. You could check it yourself in package.json before asking.

Comment: @estus: 1. `lodash` is just an example, don't pay attention to its name. 2. You're wrong in your statement `dependency a sort of a restraint, while it isn't`. I don't want to search for, evaluate, add, manage and deal with any issues in the future versions of an external dependency if something that does the same job already ships with my app. The point of the question is that **if** Angular internally (or as with RxJS - publicly) uses some lib, you **want to consider using it** before using any other means that makes the job done. So absolutely no reason to close it as off-topic.

Comment: As it was already mentioned, the only 'library' package that Angular depends on is RxJS, and this dependency is considered temporary. Not mixing a framework with 'library' stuff is the good practice among all modern frameworks for numerous reasons. Any way, I don't see a practical reason to avoid extra dependencies. If you need them, you need them. Especially if it's not about bundle size.

Comment: @estus: Not depending on dozens of external packages **if you can avoid it** is another great practice especially in web development when you'd have to deal with a kaleidoscope of new versions of just everything every day. That's exactly the point - if you **need** to depend on Angular which **already** depends on "X" **and** "X" does what you need, you **want to use "X"**. Not the "Y" (most likely "Y" + "Z1" +.. + "Zn", where Zs are inner dependencies of "Y"). If Angular doesn't actually depend on anything - that's the answer to this question.

Comment: There is a known problem with the practice you've mentioned. Version constraints. Let's say you use a library that is bundled with a framework just because it's there - instead of using an alternative that is x5 times smaller and suits the case better. Now at some point it becomes obvious that the framework relies on older library version, and you're after newer one, due to features or bug fixes. You end up with 2 versions of same big library. But if the framework doesn't allow to have 2 of them (e.g. peer dependency), you're screwed. And... we've already been there with A2 and RxJS 5.0.

Comment: @estus: Sure, this is an obvious potential issue of this approach to consider (in cases when you opt to care about it preemptively). But choosing "Y" instead of framework's "X" when "Y" is currently not used by the framework, you likewise might run into the situation that someday framework would switch to use "Y"  and you're screwed as well. Both approaches is a gamble from this point of view, but with one important difference: when you use readily available "X" (which probably has been chosen by framework author's for a reason), you likely bootstrap your app much quicker.

Comment: Again, app initialization speed depends on the footprint that lib dependency has on bundle size, not the presence of a dependency itself. Since you're new to Angular 2+ and investigating your possibilities, I can assure you that you initially gave this concern the wrong priority. It's just another thing that should be kept in mind, not a decisive factor at all.

Comment: @estus: If you mean the "don't introduce a dependency unless you've a really good reason" concern - sorry, I have to disagree with the priority you're suggesting.

Comment: It depends on what your arguments are based on. My priority is based on my own real-life Angular development experience, and also on best practices I I had a chance to learn from well-designed third-party projects. I see no reason to not introduce a dependency if it benefits the app AND has minimal to reasonable footprint - just because that's reasonable. You surely have a right to have your own opinion and learn from own mistakes, but that's the reason why off-topic and opinion-based questions aren't allowed on SO. They can provoke a nice discussion but cannot result in good unbiased answers.

Comment: @estus: Yes, that's the whole point: you base it on your personal experience, but it doesn't make it right for everyone or every situation and doesn't make other approaches something bad. And for 100%, it doesn't make questions regarding those alternative approaches you don't recommend "off topic"/"opinion-based". I believe the only "off topic"/"opinion-based" thing in the whole discussion is your tendency to reassure people to use what you're after. However, my initial question is "Do readily available 3rd party libs EVEN EXIST in an Angular app", not "Is it a good practice to use them".

Comment: Since you're new to Angular that's a bit strange that you already made an opinion about something you don't have real-world experience with. Any way, it's up to you. The initial question isn't enough clear enough on what 'readily' 'and free to use' are supposed to mean (and again, this results from wrong understanding of a relationship between Angular and RxJS, hence XY problem). Library recommendation questions are off-topic on SO, so do vague questions with unclear presupposition. Somebody with your rep should already know that.

Comment: Angular is just another JS framework, so the discussion you've started is on the topic of "JS app dep. management in general", rather than "Ang. app dep.management". Therefore, not sure why you appeal to my experience with Angular. You even don't have to be a JS developer to understand that extra dependencies make your app more fragile, since their future is not under your control. Sorry, but I'm not sure how the question "There is RxJS. Is there any other lib used by Angular in run-time, so we could use it too?" could be vague or unclear or "Library recommendation" question.

Comment: Probably, you just over-complicating my simple question due to your extended experience with Angular and having some practices you're eager to adhere to. By the way, I updated my question for the extra clarity for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although RxJS is certainly a big player in Angular's dependency pool, it's certainly not the only one, and not even the only one *you'll* need to depend on to use Angular.

Zone.js, for instance, is another key component in Angular's architecture that you'll need to depend on to use it. Although both libraries are used extensively in Angular, you are by no means mandated to use them – that being said, you'll get a lot more out of the framework if you understand `Observable`s and `Zone`s.

Other things you'll need to depend on are easily inspected in Angular-CLI's `polyfills.js` file; things like `core.js` that shim up Angular's ability to run on lower-common-denominator browsers (cough, IE). There's also multiple `@angular/*`-scoped modules you'll need for other pieces of the framework, such as forms and http.

My recommendation? Boot up a CLI project and see what ends up in the `dependencies` section of your `package.json`. RxJS and Zone.js are the big contenders, but you may be surprised by other names on the list.

Answer (score 1):

Angular is pretty buffed up, meaning it already comes with predefined strategy on how you should accomplish things. I believe it's built on RxJS so you won't be able to get rid of it.

But you don't really have to use it. When you pack your app for production it will not include all of the node_modules packages, only the ones that were used.

If you want to use a JS library that's a lot less heavyweight, and comes less structured, look into react.js and vue.js

Comment: Just as an example: Angular still seems to lack, for instance, some utility stuff which is nicely implemented in lodash. And to clarify: I'm not looking an alternative to Angular or a way to get rid of existing dependencies every Angular app has. On the contrary, my question is basically: How to get most of it by being aware of ALL libs that are available anyway?

Comment: Mhm, so you don't want to download external packages if there is already a required package that can do the job?

Comment: Exactly. If I'd know that I could use lodash without introducing extra dependencies. I will certainly use it instead of re-inventing the wheel. when I need a few things it already has.

Comment: Well you have to learn the framework. That's how you know what it has and what it doesn't. Also, it's open source, so you can take a look at the code and see what's what. Notice that rxjs is not included in Angular either. You have to add it to your package manager configuration to have it included. The tutorial includes it, but it doesn't mean that you have to use it.

Comment: @AlexanderAbakumov If you know how to do the things with Lodash this doesn't mean that it is the only way. Most common use cases for _ are covered by current native JS methods. And when it comes to observables and async stuff, you will rarely need Lodash there because RxJS has its own extensive set of operators. Indispensable `_.debounce`? No longer needed.

Comment: @HubertJarema: Some important parts of Angular APIs, which you probably would need in just every Angular app implemented via `Observable`s. So yes, they try to not make "hard" dependency on RxJS (and any other lib), but in practice you rather would have it in place anyway if you don't work on some kind of "Hello, world" app. For the purpose of this question, let's suppose that Angular has no API for a job we need to do. So, we have either to copy-paste stuff from available implementations around, or figure out what libs Angular based on and use them whenever possible.

Comment: @estus: I mentioned `lodash` just as one of coumtless examples of a 3rd party lib we might want to rely on. Angular is far from being so comprehensive that you don't need anything else. And neither is most current native JS API implementation. Just look at the number of packages in a minimalistic Angular app - you'll find about 700 packages there(!). It's probably more than in any modern software stack. Yes, 650 of them is just to support Angular build toolchain, but the rest is still required by your app to be loaded into the most recent browser.

Comment: @AlexanderAbakumov What did make you think that they are required? You are probably misunderstanding the role of the framework. It isn't supposed to be a library of utility functions (like AngularJS was  to some extent, when it tried to mimic jQuery API). If you can't do something with native JS easily, you may try to spend more time with it, it pays off.  As for me, the only libs I usually install by default for client side app are `core-js`, `moment` and `lodash.omit`. Everything else depends on the project.

Comment: @estus: So, you're saying that from those 700 packages, except `@angular/*` ones only `core-js` is required to be loaded into the browser?

Comment: @AlexanderAbakumov Check package.json `dependencies` section in your project and you'll see. As for client-side packages, Angular itself requires zone.js, rxjs and core-js to function properly. tslib is also welcome if you're using TS. That's all.

Comment: @estus: And on your second point. After removing that jQuery-related utility stuff, there is some vacuum for implementing pretty basic stuff. Modern JS API just doesn't compensate it to the extent you don't have to worry about. You still have to go through number of plain old hacks/workarounds/polyfills here and there to do even the basic work.

Comment: @AlexanderAbakumov Most things are very straightforward with ES2017+ native stuff. Much simpler than in ES5 where Lodash had some advantages for basic things. If you already know what things you are missing in JS, you can install them from NPM when you need them - _.omit, _.clonedeep, etc. And yes, there's no need to install entire Lodash if you need a couple of methods from it. If you have problems with making things efficient in raw JS, don't hesitate to ask about it - there's a bunch of 'how can I filter this array' questions every day.

Comment: @estus: Is it safe to believe that `package.json` illustrate the real picture of the dependencies tree? I mean could they pack external dependencies into the package itself or something along those lines to avoid having dependencies for the package?

Comment: @AlexanderAbakumov Of course, packages can introduce their own dependencies. The thing that matters is the footprint they have when being bundled, not package count. I usually use NPM2 locally. It has some flaws but gives a fair representation of dependency tree. Usually you shouldn't look into node_modules in NPM3+ at all because it looks ugly.

Comment: Then it seems that looking at the `package.json` is rather meaningless in this case. We need to check somehow else which packages are actually get loaded into browser.

Comment: @AlexanderAbakumov You know the real footprint with trial and error. You should just know the footprint of each package you're using if you care about bundle size. Tools like this one https://chrisbateman.github.io/webpack-visualizer/ can also help. Due to the fact that libraries that were written with ES modules in mind (Lodash isn't one of them) can be tree-shaken in Webpack/Rollup, the size of a package with dependencies isn't representative at all. RxJS is big enough but it's 80-90% smaller when it's imported only in Angular core.

Comment: @estus: For the scope of this specific question, I'm interested exclusively in minimizing of the number of extra dependencies (ideally not introducing them at all by using libs Angular is based on whenever possible). No worries about bundle size.